# LibGDX How to use viewport to support different screen sizes

Tags: android, libgdx, viewport, android-screen-support

I have been looking for a way that works for me to use viewport in my android libgdx application but all of the ones I find never seem to work. I don't use a stage, so I'm wondering if that's my problem.

For example, if I add this code to my application:

```
private Viewport viewport;
private Camera camera;

public void create() {
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    viewport = new StretchViewport(800, 480, camera);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

When I try this on a phone, it works, but then when I try it on a 7 inch tablet, all the objects in my app are too big, almost as if I need to zoom out. I have tried a lot of the viewports including FitViewport and FillViewport, but they don't seem to work. I have also tried changing the 800, 480 in the StretchViewport to 800, 600 because that's my background image size, but it didn't do anything.

This is what it looks like on a phone:

[image: Phone Image]

Then, on a tablet, it looks like this:

[image: Tablet Image]

As you can see, the tablet is more zoomed in.

Here's my render() method:

```
@Override
public void render () {

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(backgroundimg, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){

        isGoingUp = !isGoingUp;

    }

    if(gameState == 1) {

        if(obstacleX[scoringObstacle] + obstacle.getWidth() < Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 + balls[0].getWidth()){

            if(obstacleY[scoringObstacle] < Gdx.graphics.getHeight() && obstacleY[scoringObstacle] + obstacle.getHeight() > 0) {

                score++;

                if(score > highscore){

                    highscore++;

                    highscorePref.putInteger("highscore", highscore);

                    highscorePref.flush();

                }

                if(score >= 10 && score < 20){

                    obstacleVelocity = 11;//6

                }

                else if(score >= 20 && score < 30){

                    obstacleVelocity = 12;//7

                }

                else if(score >= 30 && score < 40){

                    obstacleVelocity = 13;//8

                }

            }

            if(scoringObstacle < numberOfObstacles - 1){

                scoringObstacle ++;

            }

            else{

                scoringObstacle = 0;

            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObstacles; i++){

            if (obstacleX[i] < - obstacle.getWidth()){

                obstacleX[i] += numberOfObstacles * distanceBetweenObstacles;

                obstacleY[i] = (randomGenerator.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 1.5f);

                if (obstacleY[i] > Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 200 || obstacleY[i] + obstacle.getHeight() < 200){

                    obstacleY[i] = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - obstacle.getHeight() / 2;

                }

            }

            else {

                obstacleX[i] = obstacleX[i] - obstacleVelocity;

            }

            batch.draw(obstacle, obstacleX[i], obstacleY[i]);

            if(score >= 20){

                if(obstacleX[3] < - obstacle.getWidth()){

                    bhGone = true;

                }

                if(bhGone) {

                    bhChance = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);

                    bhGone = false;

                }

                if(bhChance == 0){

                    batch.draw(blackHole, obstacleX[3] - distanceBetweenObstacles / 2 + blackHole.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - blackHole.getHeight() / 2);

                    blackHoleCircle.set(obstacleX[3] - distanceBetweenObstacles / 2 + blackHole.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, blackHole.getHeight() / 2);

                }

            }

            obstacleRectangles[i] = new Rectangle(obstacleX[i], obstacleY[i], obstacle.getWidth(), obstacle.getHeight());

            if (Intersector.overlaps(ballCircle, obstacleRectangles[i])) {

                diedByBh = false;

                gameState = 2;

            }

            else if(Intersector.overlaps(ballCircle, blackHoleCircle)){

                diedByBh = true;

                blackHoleCircle.set(0, 0, 2);

                gameState = 2;

            }

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++) {

            if (!isGoingUp) {

                if(ballY[i] >= 0) {

                    ballY[i] = ballY[i] - ballVelocity;

                }

            }

            else{

                if(ballY[i] <= Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - balls[0].getWidth()) {

                    ballY[i] = ballY[i] + ballVelocity;

                }

            }

        }

        if (ballState < 7) {

            ballState++;

        } else {

            ballState = 0;

        }

    }

    else if(gameState == 0){

        infoFont.draw(batch, "Tap to move up and down", Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4 - fontBack, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){

            gameState = 1;

        }

    }

    else if(gameState == 2) {

        if(diedByBh){

            balls[ballState] = new Texture("nothing.png");

        }

        else {

            balls[ballState] = new Texture("splatteredball.png");

        }

        infoFont.draw(batch, "Tap to play again", Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4 - fontBack, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

        highscoreFont.draw(batch, "High Score: " + String.valueOf(highscore), Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4 - fontBack, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 4 - 100);

        if(showAd) {

            showAd = false;

            adNumber = 1;

            adsController.showInterstitialAd();

        }

        else {

            if(!adNumDone) {

                if (adNumber < 15) {

                    adNumber++;

                } else {

                    showAd = true;

                }

                adNumDone = true;

            }

        }

        isGoingUp = true;

        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

            if(Gdx.input.getY() < viewport.getWorldHeight() / 2){

                adsController.showRewardedVideoAd();

            }

            else {

                adNumDone = false;

                gameState = 1;
                startGame();
                score = 0;
                scoringObstacle = 0;

            }

        }

    }

    batch.draw(balls[ballState], Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 + balls[0].getWidth(), ballY[ballState]);

    ballCircle.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 + balls[0].getWidth() + balls[ballState].getWidth() / 2, ballY[ballState] + balls[ballState].getHeight() / 2, balls[ballState].getHeight() / 2);

    scoreFont.draw(batch, String.valueOf(score), 50, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 50);

    batch.end();

}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need a screenshot to understand what the problem is. Also, don't use StretchViewport, because it results in a distorted game. Use ExtendViewport, or FitViewport if you don't mind black bars.

Comment: Also your render() method would be helpful

Comment: @Tenfour04 What about FillViewport?

Comment: @TomGrillGames my render method is really long. I don't think it would be appropriate to paste the whole thing in here. Why do you need my render method?

Comment: FillViewport results in part of your virtual viewport getting cropped off. I can't think of a game design where it's ok for some unpredictable amount of the scene to get cropped off screen. Your render method will show us if you are using the viewport correctly.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ok I added the render method and some screenshots. Thanks!

Comment: You need to call viewport.apply() before drawing with its camera.

Comment: @Tenfour04 do you mean in the create() method after the line: viewport = new StretchViewport(800, 480, camera);

Comment: At the beginning of render().

Comment: @Tenfour04 Still didn't change. I set it to FitViewport, and I didn't even see the black bars.

Comment: I didn't see before because I was on my phone, but you aren't using your camera either. Add `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)` before `batch.begin()`. You also need to call `Gdx.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` at the beginning of `render()` unless you're already doing it in an upper level class.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sticking with me. When I do this, however, my screen is black.

Comment: @Tenfour04 hi did you see my comment above I forgot to tag.

Comment: I see yet another problem. Since you are using a viewport, your positioning code for various objects in your render method should never use graphics.getHeight and getWidth. The whole reason for Viewport is to abstract away the screen dimensions. You should be working with units relative to the virtual size you gave the viewport's constructor.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Should I use `viewport.getWorldWidth()` and `viewport.getWorldHeight()` or should I use `viewport.getScreenWidth()` and `viewport.getScreenHeight()`

Comment: World, not screen. As long as your arent using FillViewport. No one should ever be using FillViewport. :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me, you led me to the solution. If you want, you could post your last comment as an answer, and I could accept it. That way you could gain reputation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sorry I forgot to tag you in the comment above